# defaultdict not available, implementation using an empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that looks like this:

```
abcd a1
abcd a2
abcd a3
abcd b1
abcd b2
q a1
q a2
```

I have a defaultdict implementation that places them in  dictionary. However, how would I do this without defaultdict(older python). My goal is to have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
abcd : 'a1','a2','a3','b1','b2'
q : 'a1', 'a2'
```

Also I need to count the number of elements in q, total number of elements in abcd and so on..

edited.

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with multiple of the same key.

Comment: @MSeifert: Counter is newer than defaultdict, though, so if you don't have defaultdict, you're not going to have Counter either.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `defaultdict` use `setdefault()`:

```
x = {}
x.setdefault('abcd', []).append('a1')
x.setdefault('abcd', []).append('a2')
```

This will result in:

```
abcd: ['a1', 'a2']
```

and works by trying to lookup `'abcd'` as key for `x` and when not avaialable, initiating it as an empty list (`[]`). and return either the found value or the newly instantiated list. The `.append()` works on the returned value (first time on the empty list, after that on the list with `a1`).

I am not sure when this was added but I have code from 2001 which uses `setdefault()` so your Python version will probably support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `__missing__` on a subclass of `dict` and create an additional `count` method to count the number of occurences of a key:

```
class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = []
        return self[key]

    def count(self, key):
        return len(self[key])

>>> a = DefaultDict()
>>> a['a'].append(1)
>>> a['a'].append(1)
>>> a['a'].append(1)
>>> a['a'].append(1)
>>> a['a'].append(1)
>>> a
{'a': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

>>> a.count('a')
5
```

Comment: additionally you can implement the the `__init__` or `__new__` such that it receive a factory function to fully imitate the defaultdict